# Add class depending on number of child divs

Tags: jquery, addclass

I have a parent div in which 2 to 4 child divs will be added dynamically. I need to count the child divs and then add a class to the parent div depending on the # of children.

```
<div id="parent">
   <div class="child">content</div>
   <div class="child">content</div>
   ...
</div>
```

Basically, I need to use jquery to say:

If there are 4 child divs, then add class ".four" to parent div.

If there are 3 child divs, then add class ".three" to parent div.

If there are 2 child divs, then add class ".two" to parent div.

I think I need to use .length(), but I can't figure out how to put it all together. I greatly appreciate any advice.

Thank you!

Comment: To help others who may need this, here's a fiddle that shows the answer that dystroy suggested. It works! Just add or delete the child divs to see the change. http://jsfiddle.net/VR2Zq/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to do it :

```
$('#parent').removeClass().addClass(function(){
    return ["none", "one", "two", "three", "four"]
       [$(this).children('.child').length];
});
```

Comment: Nice. But previous values would need to be removed if another element is added. I'd just set the CLASS instead of adding it.

Comment: Thanks so much Dystroy! That worked perfectly.

To help me understand, how does this add those classes in order along with the count? Is it the [ ] brackets that do that?